Tools for Terraform that have support for Oracle Cloud Infrastructure resources
I am working (not out of choice) with Oracle Cloud Infrastructure and would like to implement some pre commit checks, mainly linting and static infrastructure scanning + testing. Is anyone aware of tool(s) that would help me with this predicament?
Coming from an AWS background, my usual tools of choice were tflint and checkov. As far as I can tell, checkov does not support OCI and tflint had a plugin at some point (based on evidence I found in an old ticket on GitHub) but has since been removed/no longer available.

Checkov currently supports OCI for infrastructure as code. You can find the relevant documentation.
